# Jquery unrecognized expression error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #mas137-0-0-0-1|2|7|9|13
```

in the script below. I don't understand why `"ID"` can not be `"137-0-0-0-1|2|7|9|13"`. I use `"|"` delimiter because there are other conflicts if I use `","` or `":"`.

```
$(document.body).on('click','.load_more_posts',function() {
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
if(ID) {
$("#mas"+ID).html('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",url: "/show_more.php",data: "vid="+ ID, cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#mas"+ID).remove();
$("div#posts").append(html);

}});

} else {
$(".masw").html('-');
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: so the question is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the symbols that are not accepted. One way to do it is

```
var ID = $(this).attr("id").replace(/\|/g, '\\|');
```

I would still recommend you use the standard recommended symbols for ID attributes.

```js
var i = $('div').attr('id').replace(/\|/g, '\\|');
var t = $('#mask'+i).text();
alert(t);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="137-0-0-0-1|2|7|9|13"></div>
<div id="mask137-0-0-0-1|2|7|9|13">Text</div>
```